# Intercept/handle mime type/file

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, xpcom

How do you disable the default action for .torrent files/content-type application/x-bittorrent(eg open with dialog or run program) and instead handle the data in a extension?

Comment: I looked into it but I'm not sure. I looked into how firefox makes the browser the default app, it uses shell service, try investigating here: http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/browser/components/preferences/advanced.js#905

Comment: I thought about this. If you want say a user clicks a file from the OS file explorer, then you'll have to do some per OS stuff. But if you want when a user clicks a link in firefox that has some certain extension, then you can handle that via add-on. Not with the shell method in my comment prior. I gotta sit down and work on this though, too tired right now 335am!

Comment: Yeah, I want to override firefox default action when a link is clicked. I've found some old code that uses observers and filter through all requests and responses and then inlines file-attachments when it's a torrent to disable the popup dialog, but it doesn't seem to work anymore. Surely there must be a way to simply register a handle for the mime-type itself?

Comment: Ok so Firefox has a handler for mime type in the options. So you gotta mess around with it, I looked into it but I can't figure out how to set it to extension. heres the source on mxr for setting handlers for mime types: [MXR :: mozilla-release](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/browser/components/preferences/applications.js#284) and [Image of Firefox mime type to hanlder options menu](http://prntscr.com/3zk5gf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @nmaiers post this is how you do it:

This is how you do it IF the mime type already exists. If it doesn't exist I don't know how to add it, probably some register function.

For some reason the type for my `torrent`s is `application/x-download` I have no idea why. If you want info on how I figured that out than I'll tell you. So in the example below I use that as file type.

When we `console.log(wrappedHandlerInfo)` we see that it looks like this:
[image: variable viewer on wrappedHandlerInfo]

so now let's do that enumerate all application handlers (i got this from here: [MXR :: gApplicationsPane](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/browser/components/preferences/applications.js#1121), and if `.type == 'application/x-download' let's`break` so we can than play with that object.

```
var handlerService = Cc['@mozilla.org/uriloader/handler-service;1'].getService(Ci.nsIHandlerService);

var listOfWrappedHandlers = handlerService.enumerate();
var i = 0;
while (listOfWrappedHandlers.hasMoreElements()) {
  var wrappedHandlerInfo = listOfWrappedHandlers.getNext().QueryInterface(Ci.nsIHandlerInfo);
  console.log(i, 'handler for', wrappedHandlerInfo.type, wrappedHandlerInfo);
  if (wrappedHandlerInfo.type == 'application/x-download') {
    break;
  }
  i++;
}
console.log('Listed ', i, ' handlers');
console.log('wrappedHandlerInfo=', wrappedHandlerInfo); //should be the application/x-download one as we broke the loop once it found that
```

now we have to set its properties then save it.

```
// Change and save mime handler settings.
wrappedHandlerInfo.alwaysAskBeforeHandling = false;
wrappedHandlerInfo.preferredAction = Ci.nsIHandlerInfo.handleInternally;
handlerService.store(wrappedHandlerInfo);
```

### I'm not sure what to change those properties too though, maybe @nmaier can advise us on that.

We see here on [MXR :: nsIHandlerService.idl #L69](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/uriloader/exthandler/nsIHandlerService.idl#69) that store does this:

```
69    * Save the preferred action, preferred handler, possible handlers, and
70    * always ask properties of the given handler info object to the datastore.
71    * Updates an existing record or creates a new one if necessary.
72    *
73    * Note: if preferred action is undefined or invalid, then we assume
74    * the default value nsIHandlerInfo::useHelperApp.
75    *
76    * @param aHandlerInfo  the handler info object
77    */
78   void store(in nsIHandlerInfo aHandlerInfo);
```

---

## ANOTHER WAY

Ok i found an even better way, this way you don't need to loop to find the handler.

Do this:

```
var mimeService = Cc['@mozilla.org/mime;1'].getService(Ci.nsIMIMEService);
var CONTENT_TYPE = ''; //'application/x-download'; can leave this blank
var TYPE_EXTENSION = 'torrent';

var handlerInfo = mimeService.getFromTypeAndExtension(CONTENT_TYPE, TYPE_EXTENSION);
console.info('handlerInfo:', handlerInfo); //http://i.imgur.com/dUKox24.png

    // Change and save mime handler settings.
    handlerInfo.alwaysAskBeforeHandling = false;
    handlerInfo.preferredAction = Ci.nsIHandlerInfo.handleInternally;
    handlerService.store(handlerInfo);
```

This `handlerInfo` object is slightly different in that it has a `primaryExtension` attribute which holds torrent.

[image: using nsiMIMService to get the handlerinfo object]

---

## Problem with both ways

The problem with both ways is that, if the mime type doesn't exist, you have to register it somehow, I don't know how. Probably use mime service and some register function.

### Update August 3rd 2014

I think i found a solution for the problem mentioned in bullet above (problem with both ways).

[MXR :: addPossibleApplicationHandler](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/browser/components/preferences/applications.js#235)

```
235   addPossibleApplicationHandler: function(aNewHandler) {
236     var possibleApps = this.possibleApplicationHandlers.enumerate();
237     while (possibleApps.hasMoreElements()) {
238       if (possibleApps.getNext().equals(aNewHandler))
239         return;
240     }
241     this.possibleApplicationHandlers.appendElement(aNewHandler, false);
242   },
243
```

This is code for `addPossibleApplicationHandler`, we probably just need to copy that and edit somehow.

### Update August 3rd 2014

Ok this is how to add protocol handler (it only adds a nsIWebAppHandler but im sure to add a local meaning a nsIAppHandler it should be similar just no need for uri param:

https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/2faaac70c62bc13e7773#add-a-handler-to-a-protocol

---

Info on functions available in `nsIMIMEService`: MXR :: nsIMIMEService.idl

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple ways, that all boil down to `nsIMimeService`/`nsIHandlerService` and `nsIMimeInfo` and setting the appropriate `nsIHandlerInfo`. E.g. see [PDF.js making itself the handler for PDF files](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/717cd9d89a80/browser/extensions/pdfjs/content/PdfJs.jsm#l160) (by effectively disabling all handler or plugins and implementing a stream converter), or my [answer on how to register a web protocol handler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24910047/484441) (not mime related but protocol related, but the handler info stuff still applies).

Depending on how you'd like to handle things, you may use the [`nsIHandlerApp`](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/717cd9d89a80/netwerk/mime/nsIMIMEInfo.idl#l212)-ervied interfaces e.g. to pass the uri (protocols) or file (mime) directly to some local or web application, or implement a full blown stream converter like PDF.js.

In theory, it would be also possible to implement new kinds of `nsIHandlerApp`-derived interfaces, implementing in particular `launchWithURI` (protocols) or `launchWithFile` (mime content types and file extensions (downloads)). However, this is a bit tricky as `nsIHandlerService` only handles the built-in interfaces.

Comment: Thanks man for this awesome post. It wasn't a spoon feed solution and it took me week or so but I got it down. Made this simple add-on out of it for average users to install webmamil clients as mailto handlers. [AMO :: MailtoWebmails](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/mailtowebmails/). I credited you for "Protocol XPCOM Education :P