# How to set the protocol handler

Tags: firefox-addon

In the custom mailto handlers:
[image: see red arrow pointing to newlly added]

I am trying to figure out how I can dynamically mimic the setting of it. As doing `registerProtocoLHandler` only adds the handler but doesn't set it.

So I opened up the prefs pane as seen above and then did dom inspector on the box. I found some functions it was doing:

```
var me = Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow(null);
var win = Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('Browser:Preferences');
me.alert(win.gApplicationsPane.onSelectAction) //gApplicationsPane.onSelectAction(event.originalTarget)

me.alert(win.gApplicationsPane._storeAction)
```

So apparnetly on command of the dropdown it does `onSelectAction` but it passes to it `event.originalTarget`, this is where my mxr adventure drives me nuts. I couldn't figure out what its doing. Please help to mimic without having to pass `event.originalTarget` or even use the `onSelectAction` because i hope to execute from an scope where this pane is not open.

Answer (score 0):

Uh I think I answered my own question a couple weeks ago haha:
[Intercept/handle mime type/file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24560243/intercept-handle-mime-type-file)

I'll let you know what i come up with.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

This snippet sets the mailto handler to be yahoo mail if its found. If not found it tells you its not found.

Copy paste and run from scratchpad in browser environment:

```
 var handlers = handlerInfo.possibleApplicationHandlers.enumerate();
 var foundYahooMailHandler = false;
 while (handlers.hasMoreElements()) {
   var handler = handlers.getNext().QueryInterface(Ci.nsIWebHandlerApp);
   if (handler.uriTemplate == 'https://compose.mail.yahoo.com/?To=%s') { //this is how i decided to indentify if the handler is of yahoo mail
     foundYahooMailHandler = true;
     break;
   }
 }

if (foundYahooMailHandler) {
  //it was found. and in the while loop when i found it, i "break"ed out of the loop which left handlerInfo set at the yahoo mail handler
  //set this to the prefered handler as this handler is the y! mail handler
  handlerInfo.preferredAction = Ci.nsIHandlerInfo.useHelperApp; //Ci.nsIHandlerInfo has keys: alwaysAsk:1, handleInternally:3, saveToDisk:0, useHelperApp:2, useSystemDefault:4
  handlerInfo.preferredApplicationHandler = handler;
  handlerInfo.alwaysAskBeforeHandling = false;
  var hs = Cc["@mozilla.org/uriloader/handler-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIHandlerService);
  hs.store(handlerInfo);
} else {
  Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow(null).alert('could not find yahoo mail handler. meaning i couldnt find a handler with uriTemplate of ...compose.mail.yahoo....')
}
```